# How can I search array in Algolia

Tags: arrays, algolia

I've tried and I did't find solution.

This is an example for an array I have in my database:

```
{
 Users:{
    {
    "name":"User1",
    "interest":["cats"]
    },
    {
    "name":"User2",
    "interest":["dogs"]
    },
    {
    "name":"User3",
    "interest":["bird"]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to search on all user. For example, interest = cats or dogs or bird.

I read algolia documentation and there are filter feature as :"interest:cats or interest:dogs" - but this is not programmatic. How can I make it programmatic?

My second problem is when I write a cat and a dog, the result is null value, but when I write cat**s** and dog**s**(plural, like the value in the database) the result is true. How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm not sure what you mean by programmatic so I'm gonna skip this part, sorry.*

There are two aspects of search here that might get you confused. You can either search by keywords, or by filters.

Search by keyword is when you type `cats`, or even `cat` or `cast` (with a typo). Algolia will return all records that match what you typed. You can define which fields should be made searchable through the `searchableAttributes` of the index settings. In your case it would be `searchableAttributes: ['interest']`.

Search by filters is in addition to keyword search. That's when you only want results that are exactly matching a specific filter value. You first have to define `interest` as facets using `attributesForFaceting: ['interest']`, and you can then use the `interest:cats or interest:dogs` syntax. Note that for filters, the value must be written exactly as it is saved (ie. there is no typo-tolerance on it).

Hope that helps,